# Error Deployment failed: PrincipalId "***" on the resource's Identity property must be null or empty for 'SystemAssigned' identity type

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-logic-apps

I have the following `LogicApp.json` file, and I want to take it from DevOps Git to Azure with a YAML pipeline, see under.

But then I get the error:

> The principalId  "***"  on the resource's Identity property must be null or empty for 'SystemAssigned' identity type

I have tried to set

```
principalId: null
principalId: "" 
principalId: 0
```

But I keep on getting the same error. Is there any workaround for this that allows me to keep 'SystemAssigned' identity type? or what am I doing wrong?

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04- 
    01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "workflows_name": {
            "defaultValue": "dev-name1",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "connections_keyvault_2_externalid": {
            "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/****/resourceGroups/dev-rg/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/keyvault-2",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
            "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
            "name": "[parameters('workflows_name')]",
            "location": "europe",
            "tags": {
                "costCenter": "KF263",
                "responsible": "ivv@me.com"
            },
            "identity": {
                "principalId": "null",
                "tenantId": "****",
                "type": "SystemAssigned"
            },
            "properties": {
                "state": "Enabled",
                 "definition": {
                    "$schema": 
"https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {
                        "$connections": {
                            "defaultValue": {},
                            "type": "Object"
                        }
                    },
                    "triggers": {
                        "manual": {
                            "type": "Request",
                            "kind": "Http",
                            "inputs": {
                                "schema": {}
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "actions": {
                        "Get_secret": {
                            "runAfter": {},
                            "type": "ApiConnection",
                            "inputs": {
                                "host": {
                                    "connection": {
                                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['keyvault_1']['connectionId']"
                                    }
                                },
                                "method": "get",
                                "path": "/secrets/@{encodeURIComponent('quality-control-dev')}/value"
                            }
                        },
                        "HTTP": {
                            "runAfter": {
                                "Get_secret": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            },
                            "type": "Http",
                            "inputs": {
                                "authentication": {
                                    "audience": "https://*.asazure.windows.net",
                                    "clientId": "****",
                                    "secret": "@body('Get_secret')?['value']",
                                    "tenant": "****",
                                    "type": "ActiveDirectoryOAuth"
                                },
                                "body": {
                                    "CommitMode": "transactional",
                                    "MaxParallelism": 2,
                                    "RetryCount": 2,
                                    "Type": "Full"
                                },
                                "headers": {
                                    "Content Type": "application/json"
                                },
                                "method": "POST",
                                "uri": "****"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "outputs": {}
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "$connections": {
                        "value": {
                            "keyvault_1": {
                                "connectionId": "[parameters('connections_keyvault_2_externalid')]",
                                "connectionName": "keyvault-2",
                                "connectionProperties": {
                                    "authentication": {
                                        "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
                                    }
                                },
                                "id":"/subscriptions/****/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westeurope/managedApis/keyvault"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pipeline
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- develop
 pool:
 vmImage: windows-latest
steps:
 - task: VSBuild@1
   inputs:
   solution: '**\*.sln'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
   inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'azure-devops (****)'
    subscriptionId: '****'
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: 'logicapp-devops-dev'
    location: 'North Europe'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\**\LogicApp.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\**\LogicApp.parameters.json'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the line. The "tenantId" line can probably also be removed.

**Update.** This article describes it: [Enable system-assigned identity in an ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-managed-service-identity?tabs=consumption#enable-system-assigned-identity-in-an-arm-template)

[image]

Comment: Hei, thank you so much! It helped. I need to remove both, TenantId and PrincipalId properties and it worked!!

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by 10p, you need to remove both the tenantId- and principalId-properties.
When specifying the type to be SystemAssigned, the principalId will be automatically assigned upon creation of the Logic App. When redeploying the Logic App later on, the same id will still be assigned as the Azure resource (the Logic App itself) stays the same and has already been registered within your tenant.

Comment: As easy as that! thank you so much it worked :D